# Stackb0t | Messenger chatbot for Stack Overflow

Tags: app, stackoverflow, chatbot

## `Stackb0t`

#### Screenshots

Say hi / hello to get started..

[image: Say hello to get started]

Get unread inbox and reputation changes

[image: inbox and reputation changes]

### About

It sends unread inbox + reputation changes in Messenger once registered.

Why did I create it? Who is it for?

> I've been addicted to the platform for a while now. But, knowing whether someone asked or replied to your answer / comment / question was a pain once I log off (or go home). Also, I hated opening an app or website even now and then just to know whether my question got answered or answer got upvoted / accepted (or someone replied or not). So, I created this in a weekend :)
>
> I believe it's made for the geeks (like me?) who are also addicted to this platform. It is currently limited to Stack Overflow, but it can surely be extended for other Stack Exchange platforms.
>
> Who doesn't like to wake up with a bunch of upvotes and accepted answers anyway? :D

How does it work?

> Once you register it with Stack Exchange, it polls for you every five minutes and sends any new / unread activity in your inbox / reputation in your Messenger.

#### Download

`Stackb0t` is live at [**`m.me/stackb0t`**](http://m.me/stackb0t) (**Edit**: down lately, apologies)

### Contact

I created this. Get in touch: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/tanmayrajani)

### Code

Built with Node.js + MongoDB + Bootbot. Deployed on Heroku and Azure.

Code: [stackb0t GitHub repository](https://github.com/tanmayrajani/stackb0t)

Comment: What Messenger? Yahoo Messenger? MSN Messenger? Facebook Messenger?

Comment: The source wants an FB token so I guess it's Facebook Messenger.